# Problem searching a number position of column in vba

Tags: excel, vba, search

I need to know in what position is a column introducing a name. I Have this but doesn't work, a error box tells me that a Report is not defined. Report is the name of the excel that i'm working.

```
Sub busqueda()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim aCell As Range

    strSearch = InputBox("ingrese la columna")
    
    Set aCell = Report.Rows(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Value Found in Cell " & aCell.Address & _
        " and the Cell Column Number is " & aCell.Column
    Else
        MsgBox "not"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `Report`, do you mean `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")`?

Comment: yes, thk you ! .